# How to get values from e.Item on Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e using Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have a ItemTapped method from which I want to take two variables "Name" and "PersonID".

```
    void RowItemTapped(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

How can I get e.Item.Name and e.Item.PersonID ?

[image: object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var cell = (Cell)e.Item;
   var viewModel = (MyViewModel)cell.BindingContext;
   var Name = viewModel.Name;
   var PersonID = viewModel.PersonID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a cast first

```
void RowItemTapped(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
     var name = (e.Item as Person).Name;
     var id = (e.Item as Person).PersonId;
...
}
```